# Do behavior packs on BE need to be purchased by players who join the world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-behavior-packs

I purchased Minecraft (Bedrock Edition) so that my kids and I could play together (cross-platform).
I'm playing on pc they are on the switch. My question is if I purchase a behavior pack and start up a world with that pack can my kids join that world without having the pack owned? I'm trying to keep from having to purchase it 3 times?

Comment: to clarify, you are on minecraft bedrock edition, purchasing an addon from the minecraft marketplace, yes?

Comment: its whatever the crossplatform version is . Not the Java edition

Comment: so if i purchase the How to train your dragon pack.and create a world using that mod can my kids join me on that world without having the mod pack purchased on there devices as well?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can so long as the mod is from the official Minecraft marketplace. My friend on Playstation invited me (on pc) to his world and despite me not owning the pack, it still let me join and play with the goodies the modpack came with.

Enjoy!

Comment: Modpack is technically inaccurate when referring to BE. The term is behavior pack (which changes actual data (so adding mobs/running scripts)). These do not need to be downloaded by players joining the world. If there is a resource pack installed as a world resource pack, then the player joining will be prompted to download it.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Your kids don't need to buy your behavior packs again. Although sometimes the game will prompt them to download certain ones, ***NOT*** buy them.

In other words, if you already have purchased a pack and uploaded one or more to a world, then basically anyone that is allowed to join can use them so long as they download the packs (if needed).

Hope you have fun with your kids, and don't get blown up by a creeper! ;)